# Golang proper way to send json response with status

Tags: mysql, json, go, select, go-gorm

How to send `json` response with status code in response body.

**My code**

```
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var user []User
    result := db.Find(&user)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

**My result now:**

```
[
    {
        "name" : "test",
        "age" : "28",
        "email":"test@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name" : "sss",
        "age" : "60",
        "email":"ss@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name" : "ddd",
        "age" : "30",
        "email":"ddd@gmail.com"
    },
]
```

But I need to send the response with `status` code like this

```
{
    status : "success",
    statusCode : 200,
    data : [
        {
            "name" : "test",
            "age" : "28",
            "email":"test@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name" : "sss",
            "age" : "60",
            "email":"ss@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name" : "ddd",
            "age" : "30",
            "email":"ddd@gmail.com"
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want different json, pass a different object to `Encode`.

```
type Response struct {
    Status       string `json:"status"`
    StatucCode   int    `json:"statusCode"`
    Data         []User `json:"data"`
}

func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var user []User
    result := db.Find(&user)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&Response{"success", 200, result})
}
```

Or use a `map`:

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]interface{}{
    "status": "success", 
    "statusCode": 200, 
    "data": result,
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, you can just add the status code like this:

```golang
func getUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var user []User
    result := db.Find(&user)
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) // adding a status 200
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```